# Spring Integration - handlers vs interceptors

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In Spring Integration, handlers and interceptors look like they basically achieve the same thing.  There are even some 'duped' implementations, such as `MessageTransformingChannelInterceptor` and `MessageTransformingHandler`, which as far as I can tell provide the same functionality with different semantics.

Is there a time when one is appropriate and not another?  If it's a matter of preference then I'm guessing that there'd be some sort of convention?

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: Handler and Interceptors are different things. The fact that there is an interceptor which provided, roughly, the same functionality as an existing handler doesn't matter. A handler is an endpoint (like a service activator, gateway etc.) whereas an interceptor is for applying generic behavior to a channel (logging, security or sometimes transformation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is to use interceptors sparingly; and typically, only for "passive" things like logging, wire tap etc.

Some users like to do message validation in interceptors; especially if they want to apply the same validation to multiple channels, perhaps with a global interceptor with an appropriate channel pattern.

The transforming interceptor was created in a very early iteration of the framework (2008) and we should probably remove (at least) the only mention of it in the reference (in the XML section).

Answer (score 2):

**handlers vs interceptors**

- **Scope**: *Handlers* primarily process messages within their designated flow, while *interceptors* can influence multiple message flows.
- **Execution**: *Handlers* are directly invoked within the message flow, while *interceptors* execute around handlers.
- **Focus**: *Handlers* focus on core message processing, while *interceptors* add supplementary behaviour or control.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor-vs-filter